# Best way to read all columns into a string

Tags: c#, .net

I have following code to read result of a SqlDataReader. I need to create resultVal string by reading each row. I need to read each column value and concatenate with the resultVal. However I will not know the number of columns present in the query result beforehand.

Currently I am using a `try..catch` approach as shown below which is not efficient.
. One alternative is to use `FieldCount` property of datareader as given in [Get number of columns in SqlDataReader](http://www.java2s.com/Code/VB/Database-ADO.net/GetnumberofcolumnsinSqlDataReader.htm)

Is there a better way to get all the column and row values into a string?

Note: I am using .Net 2.0

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(resultVal))
            {
                resultVal = reader.GetString(0);
            }
            else
            {
                resultVal = resultVal + "___" + Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(0));
            }

            try
            {
                if (reader.GetValue(1) != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    resultVal = resultVal + "-" + Convert.ToString( reader.GetValue(1));
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                //do nothing
            }


        }
    }
    else
    {
        //EmptyLogFunction(spStatement);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `FieldCount` property of the `SqlReader`. Also, it's better to use a `StringBuilder` when concatenating strings.

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        if (sb.Length > 0) sb.Append("___");
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                if (reader.GetValue(i) != DBNull.Value)
                    sb.AppendFormat("{0}-", Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(i)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But you didn't use it in your code? What's wrong with that?